# How to debug a hung call to ClientWebSocket.ReceiveAsync

Tags: c#, websocket, .net-4.8, clientwebsocket

I have a C# Windows Forms Application that sends and receives data using `ClientWebSocket`.
At some point, the call to `ClientWebSocket.ReceiveAsync` hangs and doesn't return.

```
WebSocketReceiveResult webSocketReceiveResult = await ClientWebSocket.ReceiveAsync(arraySegment, CancellationTokenSourceReceive.Token);
```

While the call is hung, the connection remains open. The client can still send messages to the server and the server continues to send messages to the client; the incoming messages can be seen in a fiddler trace.

What tools are available in Visual Studio to debug this?

Comment: Fiddler is the best tooo to understand issue.  You already determined that the connection remain open.  HTTP uses TCP as transport layer.  You should see a [FIN] at TCP level when connection closes.  Read the Microsoft documentation.  It is confusing.  The client websocket looks like it is used as part of a controller and completes when the <TResults> is found.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.websockets.websocket.receiveasync?source=recommendations&view=net-6.0

Comment: TResults is serialized data of a class and is usually json or binary.  I suspect what is happening is the results is json and some closing tags may be missing.  Or the type of object that is returning isn't matching the content type.